# AWS Cognito Identity Null

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito for user authentication, I'm trying to test unauthenticated users but all I get from Cognito is a null identity. The code below is on a viewDidLoad method:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                       credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                       accountId:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                       identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                       unauthRoleArn:@"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Cognito_XXXXXXXXXUnauth_DefaultRole"
                       authRoleArn:@"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Cognito_XXXXXXXXXAuth_DefaultRole"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

[[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
    NSString* cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId;
    NSLog(@"cognitoId: %@", cognitoId);
    //[self launchCount];
    return nil;
}];
```

So from the NSLog above I'm getting:

```
cognitoId: (null)
```

Below is the cognito authentication policy for authorized and unauthorized users:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
  "Effect":"Allow",
  "Action":"cognito-sync:*",
  "Resource":["arn:aws:cognito-sync:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:identitypool/${cognito- identity.amazonaws.com:aud}/identity/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
  }]
}
```

Any ideas what could it be, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi i already did this kind of the authentication and question is do you configure Identity Pool and roles for the cognite?

Comment: Yes I configured them, the above config is for authorized and unauthorized roles.

Comment: Show the error from code block below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please run this code and tell error.

```
[[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task){

if (task.error == nil)
{
   NSString* cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId;
   NSLog(@"cognitoId: %@", cognitoId);               
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", task.error);
}

return nil;
}];
```

Comment: It actually worked, cognito responded me with the following: cognitoId: us-east-1:a84b2f24-2759-48ce-aee1-80dcbb694919 so, can you explain to me what happened?

Comment: You're problem solved.You are connected properly.If yes please check correct answer.